# Where do I ask for tech-support for my Blu-Ray player?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a technical support question about my Blu-Ray player:

> Freeze-frame problem in Netflix on my Blu-Ray player
>
> For the past couple years or so, I've had a problem with my Sony BDP-S570 Internet-enabled Blu-Ray player.  When I stream a TV show or movie on Netflix, every minute or two the frame freezes for a few seconds.  This isn't a problem with how my Blu-Ray player plays videos in general; there's no freeze-frame issue when I watch Hulu or Blu-Ray discs.  Only Netflix gives this problem.
>
> So can anyone tell me what the problem is, and how to fix it?

My question is, what Stack Exchange site, if any, can I post this question in?  The only relevant site I can think of is Super User, but I think the question would be deemed off-topic as an Internet-enabled Blu-Ray player probably doesn't qualify as a computer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no sites covering Q&A for tech support, trouble-shooting or gear talk for home entertainment system or consumer electronics. After many attempts, sites like "Gadgets", "Home Theater", and attempts to target all "Consumer Electronics" have never gathered enough support to create a healthy site.

Comment: Interesting that [this gadgets proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets), started by no other than Joel, was launched but failed the beta phase. So you say there's no hope for such a proposal, i.e. no point trying to re-start it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard "Gadgets" was the first of many failed sites launched on the mistaken premise: *"If we build it, they will come."* We don't do that anymore. If someone suggests a comprehensive proposal that gathers widespread support in Area 51 first, it has just as much hope as anything else proposed there.